# Clicking a link in RadGrid using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, telerik-grid

I bind records using RadGrid, and each row it has a link button. If I click the link, it will open the moalpopup (it is dynamic one based on some condition). When I close the popup using close button, it should continue with the link button event.

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void grid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.Item)
    {
        LinkButton link = ((LinkButton)gridDataItem.FindControl("link"));
        ModalPopupExtender popup = (ModalPopupExtender)e.Item.FindControl("popup");
        Image imageClose = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imageClose");
        popup.TargetControlID = link.ID;
        link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;"); // to avoid postback and stay in page and show popup
        imageClose.Attributes.Add("onclick", "proceed('" + link.ClientID + "')");
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function proceed(id)
{
    window.document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute("onclick"); // Link button - to remove "onclick" attribute
    window.document.getElementById(id).click(); //  trigger click event
}
```

I tried with the above code, the attribute not removed and not continue with link button event.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done. This one worked perfectly as I expected.

```
function proceed(id)
{
    document.location.href = $('#' + id).attr("href");
}
```